# React component not recognizing .filter as a function

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

So I am making a react app for food recipes and am pulling data from a JSON file. For some reason the .filter and .map of the recipes is not showing as a function. Any help greatly appreciated.

It most examples it looks like you can add this info under render. I am a noob with both coding and react so I am sure it is user error.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReadInput from'./readInput';
import '../Styles/Home.css';

 class Input extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     this.state = {
         value:''
     }
     this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
 };
handleName(e){
    console.log('handleName')
    if(e === 'chicken'){
            this.setState({value: 1})
        } else if (e === 'beef') {
            this.setState({value: 2})
        } else if (e === 'rice'){
            this.setState({value: 3})
        }

}


render(){
    const menu = this.props.data.filter((recipe) => {
            if(recipe.id === this.state.value){
            return recipe.dish;
        }
    })
    .map(recipe => {
        return(
            <div>
            <li key={recipe.id}>{recipe.dish}</li>
            <li >{recipe.ingredients}</li>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return(
        <div>
            <ReadInput
                onChange={this.handleName} />
            <button className="homeButton" onClick={this.menu}>Click</button>
            <ul className='listStyle'>
                {menu}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
export default Input;
```

app file

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from'./Input';
import recipes from'../data.json';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super();

}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Input data={recipes} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: Where are you using this Input component? Seems like `this.props.data` is either undefined or not an Array.

Comment: @garrettmaring I added the app where I am using the input... the recipes is the content from my json file

Comment: I don't think you can just import a JSON file like that and expect it to work like an array. You either need to export the array from a JS file, or, read the JSON file and parse it before using it like an array.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @azizpunjani I thought since there is a loader in the webpack it would work... but you may be right

Comment: provide a `static defaultProps = { data: [] }` to your component, to be safe, also check what kind of data you are passing, try to log right after importing to see if it's working. learn how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout function or check your response, it may come later, before that your function may running. use timeout and check it.

```
if (timerid) {
 clearTimeout(timerid);
}

timerid = setTimeout(() => {
 this.reqMaq(obj['fkmaqid'])
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

If `this.props.data` is an object, you cannot directly map or filter on it. I think this should work:

```
const recipes = this.props.data;
const menu = Object.keys(recipes).filter((recipeKey) => recipes[recipeKey].id === this.state.value)
.map(recipeKey => 
  return (
    <div key={recipes[recipeKey].id}>
      <li>{recipes[recipeKey].dish}</li>
      <li>{recipes[recipeKey].ingredients}</li>
    </div>
  );
});
```

First you filter the keys of your `this.props.data`, you only get the keys for the recipes that match the id in the state.
Then you map (still mapping with the keys of the object, not the values) and create the list.

Notice that I moved the key attribute to the `<div>` tag, that's because you need this attribute in the component returned by the map, not in it's children.

Also, in the `<button className="homeButton" onClick={this.menu}>Click</button>`, the onClick attribute receives the menu, but it should receive a function to execute when the button is clicked.